# Internet Explorer file download Excel file filename

Tags: windows, internet-explorer, excel, vba

I have a bespoke application that downloads an Excel file from the network

The Excel file has a macro within the Workbook Open event. I have noticed that if I put the following code in the event

```
MsgBox Application.ThisWorkbook.Name
```

I can see that when the file `"PWABCD.XLS"` is opened from Internet Explorer 8, the messagebox shows `"PWABCD(1).XLS"`. When the same operation is done from Internet Explorer 10, the message box shows `"PWABCD.XLS"`.

Where is the setting that says the file download name should have (1) inserted? Or is there some other conflict that is causing the (1) to be inserted into the filename? I have inherited logic that assumes the (1) will be there and removes it - rather than amend the code to check for the existence of the (1), is there a setting the user can amend?

Many thanks

Answer (score 1):

The (1) is automatically added to the filename if another file with the same name exists in the destination directory.  There is no way to avoid this other than testing to see if the file already exists and deleting it if it does.